# Why won't my battery stop charging?

Tags: laptop, battery, charging

[image]

I don't know why this is happening but this is a new battery.
Details of which are visible in the photo.

The problem is that even after the battery meter shows 100%, the power light on the laptop that indicates whether the laptop battery is being charged stays on. I kept it like that for a few mins to see if it would stop glowing, but it did not.
Has the circuit inside died ? What is the cause ?

---

Laptop: HP Pavilion DV4-2126TX
OS: Win7 Home Premium 32bit

Comment: Is that new battery? Did you calibrate it? HP must have article about calibration of battery because sometimes battery reading isn't accurate liek in my case now. My DELL battery wear level is 45% unlike yours which is 8% and yesterday after turning on my laptop the meter showed 60% of charge available when after 1 minute of work it suddenly showed 6% and advised immediate charge. So I quickly put it on charge because I did not want sudden shutdown and loss of unsaved work.

Comment: @Boris_yo calibration was needed. Did the job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well battery charging is mostly regulated by hardware, and cannot be changed. Some laptops (Toshiba i know of) lately have options in their software to regulate the level you want to keep it charged. This because KEEPING YOUR BATTERY AT 100% WILL QUICKLY DEGRADE YOUR BATTERY. I'm writing in capitals, because it is very important information that's unfortunately not shared with us by most users / manufacturers. Now that I am using my battery everyday, and making sure I don't keep it fully charged without using it, i am using my second and third battery for 3-4 years. (versus less then 1.5 years for my first one)

REMINDER: it's actually BETTER to charge/use it/charge/useit/charge... then 'tring to save your battery' by using AC power all the time!!!

Comment: No, it's not. By keeping your laptop on AC power all the time, the management system can drain the battery or not drain the battery, whatever is best to optimize its life and performance. By not connecting the laptop to AC power, you give it no choice but to drain it, whether that's best or not.